# Intellij Idea plugin - possibility to click on an link of class/file to open it

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

Could you please suggest how is it possible to implement the next thing : when the user clicks on the file name/line number, the editor is switched to that file.

[image]

P.S. The source code is available [there](https://github.com/stkiller/IntellijIdeaReviewPlugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following classes/methods:

- [com.intellij.execution.filters.TextConsoleBuilder#addFilter](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/TextConsoleBuilder.java#L26)
- [com.intellij.execution.filters.RegexpFilter](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/RegexpFilter.java#L34)

Usage example:

- [org.intellij.lang.xpath.xslt.run.CustomRegexpFilter](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/xpath/xpath-lang/src/org/intellij/lang/xpath/xslt/run/CustomRegexpFilter.java#L50)
- [org.intellij.lang.xpath.xslt.run.XsltRunConfiguration#getState](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/xpath/xpath-lang/src/org/intellij/lang/xpath/xslt/run/XsltRunConfiguration.java#L119)

See also [Output Filters Dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/output-filters-dialog.html) help section.

Comment: Thank you :) Btw, do you know how to make the console editable ?

Comment: You can use 2 different components in the console, one for the output, another for the input.